# joining two function php

Tags: php

By some sorts of functions I am returning values of two functins... LIke

```
<? if(check_status_ticket($result["ticket_id"])) echo 'style="font-weight:bold;"'; ?>
```

Second condition is

```
 <? if($result["priority"]=='Emergency' && $result["status"]=='Open')  echo 'style="color:red;"';?>
```

I want to combine these two conditions using function. That if first condition is true it returns only bold. If second condition is also true it gives red and bold but if both are false it return default

```
function check_status_ticket( $ticket_id ){
      $query = mysql_query( "SELECT ticket_id FROM tkt_newticket WHERE ticket_id='".$ticket_id."' AND response='No' AND status='Open'" ) or die( mysql_error() );
      if(mysql_num_rows($query)=='0'){
          return FALSE;
          }
     else{
      return TRUE; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution maybe helps you

```
function check_status_ticket( $ticket_id ){
  $query = mysql_query( "SELECT ticket_id, priority, status FROM tkt_newticket WHERE ticket_id='".$ticket_id."' AND response='No' AND status='Open'" ) or die( mysql_error() );

  if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

      if($row["priority"]=='Emergency' && $row["status"]=='Open') return 'style="font-weight:bold; color:red;"';

      return 'style="color:red;"';
  } else return 'style="font-weight:bold;"';
```

}

Comment: The use of "magic numbers" doesn't make this very readable...

Comment: check out how it looks now, you're right seems more readable now... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// ...

// prepare useful variables to ease HTML template reading
$status_ticket = check_status_ticket($result["ticket_id"]);
$open_emergency = ($result["priority"]=='Emergency' && $result["status"]=='Open');

// ...

?>

<html>
...
<?php
  // little computing for style (easy to maintain, but it may be
  // even easier by using CSS classes)

  $style = '';

  if ($status_ticket)
    $style .= 'font-weight:bold;';

  if ($open_emergency)
    $style .= 'color:red;';
?>
<!--
  display step.
  <div> can be replaced by any tag you dream to apply the $style on
-->
<div style="<?php echo $style ?>"></div> 
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just evaluate the second condition first, and set multiple styles?

```
function check_status_ticket( $ticket_id )
{       
 $query = mysql_query( "SELECT ticket_id FROM tkt_newticket WHERE ticket_id='".$ticket_id."' AND response='No' AND status='Open'" ) or die( mysql_error() );       
 if(mysql_num_rows($query)=='0'){           
  return FALSE;           
 }else{       

  if(check_status_ticket($result["ticket_id"])) 
  {
   return 'style="font-weight:bold;"';
  }

  if($result["priority"]=='Emergency' && $result["status"]=='Open')
  {
   return 'style="color:red; font-weight:bold"';
  }

  return TRUE; 
 } 
} 


echo "<a href='#checkticket' " . check_status_ticket($ticket_id) . " class='ticket_class'>";
```